# Need to supply DB password to run evolutions at run time - Play + Slick

Tags: database, playframework, slick, hikaricp, playframework-evolutions

I need to avoid storing plain text passwords in config files, and so I'm storing the Postgres password externally (in AWS Secrets Manager).

Similarly to the solution provided here:
[Encrypted database password in Play + Slick + HikariCP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32385411/encrypted-database-password-in-play-slick-hikaricp-application?rq=1), I've been able to override dbConfig and supply the password to my DAO classes like this:

```
trait MyDaoSlick extends MyTableDefinitions with HasDatabaseConfig[MyPostgresDriver] {
  protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider
  override protected val dbConfig: DatabaseConfig[MyPostgresDriver] = secretDbConfig(dbConfigProvider)
  def secretDbConfig(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider): DatabaseConfig[MyPostgresDriver] = {
    DatabaseConfig.forConfig[MyPostgresDriver]("", dbConfigProvider.get[MyPostgresDriver].config
      .withValue("db.user", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(getUN))
      .withValue("db.password", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(getPWD)))
  }
}
```

This works great for regular DB queries, however evolutions bypass this and still expect the username and the password to be in application.conf, which kind of defeats the purpose of the password being a secret.

Any advice on how evolutions could get the DB credentials from a function?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, and I managed to resolve it like this:

1. Create a custom application loader, as shown here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#Advanced:-Extending-the-GuiceApplicationLoader
2. Inside the custom loader's builder, append the DB configuration parameters for Slick:

```
    val extra = Seq(
        "slick.dbs.default.db.url" -> secrets.url,
        "slick.dbs.default.db.user" -> secrets.user,
        "slick.dbs.default.db.password" -> secrets.pass
      )
```

Nothing else needs to be changed, as you've basically added the configuration needed for anything Slick, evolutions included.

On older versions of Play, we used to do this inside `GlobalSettings.onLoadConfig`, but, at some point, that has been deprecated in favour of DI. More details here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/GlobalSettings